# Creating combination of different elements in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp

I have a list of words:

```
['The', 'president', 'control'...].
```

And I have different POS tags for each word. For example:

```
{The: {DT}, president: {NP}, control: {NP, VB}...}.
```

Now I need to compute all combinations possible for the statement, for example:

```
[The_DT, president_NP, control_NP] --> Ist Combination
[The_DT, president_NP, control_VB]  --> 2nd Combination
```

Any help on how can I do so?

Comment: Can you please use real python code for your examples and show your attempt?

Comment: Parse through the string, split by `,`; now for each element split by `:` create a dictionary.. Think on these lines..

Comment: `itertools.product(*map(tags.get, sentence))` => `[[DT, NP, NP], ...]`.

Comment: got it : `import itertools
for items in itertools.product([('control','VB'), ('control','NN')],[('s','VBS'),('s','POS')],[('control','VB'),('control','NN')]):
    print items`